# Typescript Function Variable Typecheck

Tags: typescript

I want to write a function that only accepts variables if passed as I have defined it. For some reason I guess I am doing it wrong because the function still allows me to pass whatever JSON. See code below

```
type MetaObject = {
  title: string;
  meta_keywords: string,
  meta_description: string,
  og_title: string,
  og_description: string,
  image:string
}
```

I also tried

```
interface MetaObject {
  title: string;
  meta_keywords: string,
  meta_description: string,
  og_title: string,
  og_description: string,
  image:string
}
```

My Function

```
setMetaData(data: MetaObject) {

}
```

Running the function

```
this.meta.setMetaData({whatever: 'sure'});
```

I see that I get in error if I literally type what is above, what is actually in my code is

```
this.meta.setMetaData(response.body)
```

The issue is response.body does NOT match MetaObject. I guess it has no way of knowing since it is an HTTPReponse?

Comment: Using that code, I get an error in the Typescript Playground. Also, not JSON.

Comment: Typescript error: "Argument of type '{ whatever: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MetaObject'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'whatever' does not exist in type 'MetaObject'."

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwEMDyAjAVhAxsKBeKA3gFBRTACWwANhAFxQDOwATuQHYDmA3CVALbwEAfQDWEEAHcA9swAmDek1acANLwGIhsiA0yswFKW0Ut2HNaSkchFanUanVvK1p17yB8kZPLzvcnwIHHRKZkQAvkREAGYArmzYXmyM8HCIACIIiAAUslkI9GnI6FjAAJSEkQypgpk5BBIAFlkQAG4QzPQA5AyxzBBd4WVcQA

Comment: I see that in the playground it does error. Does that have to do with it all being in the same file? When I do that it works. The problem is this is a meta service that I will be calling from different components. The other components don't seem to care about the type I set in the meta service.

Comment: If you are passing in an "any" then there won't be any type checking. The type checking of Typescript is compile time. You can check to validate your data, bur you need to do that manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your members `optional` and use `interface`.

```
interface MetaObject {
  title?: string;
  meta_keywords?: string;
  meta_description?: string;
  og_title?: string;
  og_description?: string;
  image?: string;
}

function setMetaData(data: MetaObject) {

}

setMetaData({title: 'sure'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this awesome library for TypeScript JSON type validation. I've used this professionally on large scale applications and it's a pleasure.

https://github.com/mojotech/json-type-validation